# Cannot deserialize the current JSON array

Tags: c#, json, linq, serialization, json.net

I execute a query from linq that gives me a list of columns
Here's the query:

```
var userList = context.Users.Where(x => x.UserFirstName.Contains(value.ToString()) && x.UserAccessLevel == (int)AuthUser.AuthUserUserType.Manager)
                        .Select(x =>new UserGridDetails(){ UserFirstName = x.UserFirstName, UserLastName = x.UserLastName, UserEmailAddress = x.UserEmailAddress})
                        .ToList();

                output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userList);
```

Here's the JSON Data from the query

```
[{"UserFirstName":"Manager3","UserLastName":"ManagerLastName","UserEmailAddress":"manager3@test.com"}]
```

I'm trying to deserialize this data into a C# class object which has the following class

```
public class UserJsonWrapper
{
    public List<UserGridDetails> UserGridDetailses { get; set; }

}

public class UserGridDetails
{
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
    public string UserEmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the deserialize code

```
 UserJsonWrapper jsonToDataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserJsonWrapper>(value);
```

Comment: Does this all happen in one method? So are you serializing the data and subsequently deserializing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the wrapper. You're given an array, not an object containing an array as a property.

```
var jsonToDataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UserGridDetails>>(value);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be List<UserGridDetails>? as the list of type UserGridDetails and the resultant list is of that type?

Comment: @SyedAbbasZakirHussain Yes, sorry, it should be. I'll fix it up